# Cucumber-Puppeteer - Trying to scroll so element will be visible - scroll not working

Tags: scroll, cucumber, puppeteer

This is in world.js of a cucumber puppeteer project.

I realized that the the element I'm trying to find with querySelector is not on the screen initially so I want to scroll to right.

So I added code to scroll but screenshot shows scroll did not happen.
It also shows that scrollbars are visible.

```
async getForecastStartColumn(selector, attribute, wait = 0) {
      let forecast;
      await this.page.waitFor(wait);

      await this.page.evaluate(_ => {
         window.scrollBy(3000, 0);
      });

      await this.page.waitFor(1000);
      await this.page.screenshot({ path: './world-177.png', fullPage: true });
      result = await this.page.document.querySelector('div[class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable 
          grid-column-header-forecast"]');
   }

//rest of code omitted
```

Comment: Hi Steven, can you provide me with URL or example to can try to solve your problem locally in my device.

Comment: Unfortunately this site requirers login and I don't have permission to give out credentials. I mad a short video to demo the problem. Here is link https://youtu.be/NqFA-IeXDLk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to scroll right.

```
const left = $(document).outerWidth() - $(window).width();
$('body, html').scrollLeft(left);
```

```
async getForecastStartColumn(selector, attribute, wait = 0) {
      let forecast;
      await this.page.waitFor(wait);

      await this.page.evaluate(_ => {
         const left = $(document).outerWidth() - $(window).width();
         $('body, html').scrollLeft(left);
      });

      await this.page.waitFor(1000);
      await this.page.screenshot({ path: './world-177.png', fullPage: true });
      result = await this.page.document.querySelector('div[class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable 
          grid-column-header-forecast"]');
   }

//rest of code omitted
```

Edit 1

I'm using pure js not jQuery. You should know the element which scrolling right and **replace** `'html'` with selector of this element to can scroll to right.

I'm using `.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)` to can scroll to left, right, top and button. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo). and using `.scrollWidth` this is the width of the content of element in pixels. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth). and using `.pageYOffset` to get current `y` offset of element to keep this position during scrolling. becouse `.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)` need to `x` and `y`. we need to change `xpos` only and keep `ypos` value. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset).

```
async getForecastStartColumn(selector, attribute, wait = 0) {
      let forecast;
      await this.page.waitFor(wait);

      await this.page.evaluate(_ => {
         const terget = document.querySelector('html');
         terget.scrollTo(terget.scrollWidth, terget.pageYOffset);
      });

      await this.page.waitFor(1000);
      await this.page.screenshot({ path: './world-177.png', fullPage: true });
      result = await this.page.document.querySelector('div[class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable 
          grid-column-header-forecast"]');
   }

//rest of code omitted
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. 1. Do I have to require jquery? 2 Why do you call it scrollLeft. I want to scrollRight. Thank you.

Comment: I update my code. 1. it's not required to use jQuery. 2. in jQuery to scroll left or right you should use `scrollLeft()` method. lets say you use `scrollLeft(0)` you will go to left. when you set position big number it will go to right `scrollLeft(10000)`.